# model multicultual paradise

Tags: grammar

> This poetry is portraying a **model multicultural paradise.**

This sentence sounds awkward for me. It sounds like two nouns (model, multicultural paradise) are coming at the same time. Can someone explain whether this sentence is grammatically correct?

Comment: model can also be an adjective...

Comment: ... as any dictionary will tell you.

Comment: well i'm using google dictionary, and it does not tell me any adjective meanings

Comment: I was surprised to see that many dictionaries don't include the adjectival use.  Oxford Living Dictionaries and Cambridge (BrE) don't, although M-W and Cambridge (AmE) include it.  To be fair, although OLD doesn't class it as an adjective, it acknowledges that the noun can be used as a "modifier", and gives examples of this; and Cambridge gives similar examples.

Comment: They are adjectives here, and nouns can modify other nouns btw *Oil painting, Christmas night....*

Comment: I think it's probably debatable here whether "model" is an adj. or just a noun used as a modifier - though I think of it as an adj.  Either way, it's an established usage of the word "model" and perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many of the comments pointed out, "model" can act as an adjective (although some dictionaries still classify it as a noun that can act as a "modifier").

> **[model](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/model)** (adj): *serving as or capable of serving as a pattern, "a model student"*

The *style* can be slightly improved by replacing

> the poetry is portraying 
>   with
>
> the poetry **portrays**

but otherwise the grammar is fine, and the meaning should now be clear: a "model" (serving as an ideal pattern) "multicultural" (representing many cultures) "paradise" (a perfect place)